# Calculation using checkbox in the survey on visualforce and apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to build a survey which collect information from the user for quality measurement. User needs to answer the question using checkbox to complete the survey. Each checkkbox will represent a point at the back.  After the survey is completed, then I need to calculate the average of the questions based on the checkbox.  How can I do the calculation if user answers the survey using the checkbox in Visualforce?

Comment: It would be helpful if you exposed your data model

Answer (score 0):

If the questions are part of a custom object as fields, probably the easiest method that is the most extensible is to create a `List` of field names you want to count, and iterate through it on submission:

```
List<String> checkboxFields = new List<String>{'fieldname1__c', 'fieldname2__c'...};

public pageReference submit()
{
    record.total__c = 0;
    for (String field : checkboxFields)
    {
        if ((Boolean)record.get(field))
            record.total__c++;
    }
    update record;
}
```

Alternatively, if the questions are only contained on the Visualforce page, you can implement each one in a wrapper class and use `apex:repeat` to enumerate them on the page:

Controller:

```
List<String> questions = new List<String>{'Question 1'};
List<QuestionWrapper> questionAnswers = new List<QuestionWrapper>();

public PageController()
{
    for (String question : questions)
        questionAnswers.add(new QuestionWrapper(question));
}

public PageReference submit()
{
    record.total__c = 0;
    for (String i : questionAnswers.KeySet())
    {
        record.total__c += questionAnswers[i].answer ? 1 : 0; //Alternate form to first section, record.total__c += Integer.valueOf(questionAnswers[i].answer) may also work
    }
}

public class QuestionWrapper
{
    public String question;
    public Boolean answer;

    public QuestionWrapper(String question)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = false;
    }
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:repeat variable="{!questionAnswers}" var="questionAnswer">
    <apex:outputLabel value="{!questionAnswer.question}" for="checkbox"/>
    <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkbox" value="{!questionAnswer.answer} />
</apex:repeat>
```

If for whatever reason the formatting precludes using `apex:repeat`, you can still use controller variables for each question.  You may even still be able to use a list of variables and put each one in the value specifically, though I've never tried it.